# Excel VBA - send mail based on condition only working for first range

Tags: excel, vba, email, conditional-statements

I would like to send a email based on a condition for different cells and different condition.
Unfortunately my code is only working for the first range ("A4" to "H4").

If I change something else it won't be triggered.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Additional: I would like to write the 4 cells above the affected cell inside the email.
e.g. A4 will trigger the condition I would like to write the value of "A2, A3
B2, B3" inside the email.
Somebody may have an idea how to pick a area of 4x4 above the  affected cell?! Is this possible or do I need to harcdoce this inside my code?!

Thanks.

btw: I know my code is quite bad, but I'm very new at VBA, soo I'm just happy if it's working. :D

**Originally code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rg1, rg2, rg3, rg4, rg5, rg6, rg7, rg8, rg9, rg10 As Range
    Dim rg11, rg12, rg13, rg14, rg15, rg16, rg17, rg18, rg19, rg20 As Range

  Set rg1 = Intersect(Range("A4", "H4"), Target)
    If rg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
' ... similar for all ranges (with different range and condition)
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    If MsgBox("Senden?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
         xMailBody = "test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "test2" & vbNewLine & _
              "test3"
        On Error Resume Next
        With xOutMail
            .To = "test@test.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "send by cell value test"
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xOutMail = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        MsgBox "Mail verschickt!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Abgebrochen!"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Update (new Code):**

I have changed my code a little bit, unfortunately I have now a "infinity" loop, sending a mail is now triggered around 10 times... 
May somebody is able to see the issue why this is occuring?
(now at least it's triggered for every cell I want)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    If Intersect(Range("A4", "H4"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("I4", "L4"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A10", "D10"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("E10", "H10"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("I10"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 51 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("K10"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A16", "F16"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("G16", "J16"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("K16"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 3 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A22", "L22"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A28", "F28"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A57"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 26 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("D57"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 16 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("G57"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A65"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("D65", "H65"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A79", "E79"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A94", "H94"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A100", "H100"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A106"), Target) Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 2 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    If MsgBox("Senden?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
         xMailBody = "test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "test2" & vbNewLine & _
              "test3"
        On Error Resume Next
        With xOutMail
            .To = "test@test.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "send by cell value test"
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xOutMail = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        MsgBox "Mail verschickt!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Abgebrochen!"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

## Update2:

Great, it's now working with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next


    If Not Intersect(Range("A4", "H4"), Target) Is Nothgin Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("I4", "L4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A10", "D10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("E10", "H10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("I10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 51 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("K10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A16", "F16"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 31 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("G16", "J16"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("K16"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 3 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A22", "L22"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A28", "F28"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A57"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 26 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("D57"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 16 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("G57"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A65"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("D65", "H65"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A79", "E79"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A94", "H94"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A100", "H100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("A106"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 2 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    If MsgBox("Senden?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
         xMailBody = "test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "test2" & vbNewLine & _
              "test3"
        On Error Resume Next
        With xOutMail
            .To = "test@test.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "send by cell value test"
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xOutMail = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        MsgBox "Mail verschickt!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Abgebrochen!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

1. `If rg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`: This says that if there is no intersection between `Target` and `Range("A4", "H4")` then the sub should exit. I suppose you've meant that the following condition should be evaluated only if there was an intersection, so something like this:

   ```
   If Not rg1 Is Nothing Then
       If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 21 Then
           Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
       End If`
   End If
   ```
2. There is [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of Logical operators in VBA. This means that when you write `If x And y Then` both `x` and `y` will be evaluated. In your case it means that even if `IsNumeric(Target.Value)` is false the `Target.Value < 21` will be evaluated. If `Target.Value` is some string, it will raise an error.
3. [Added] There is no need to evaluate the other intersections if one was already found. You should exit the sub:

   ```
   If Not rg1 Is Nothing Then
       If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
           If Target.Value < 21 Then
               Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
               Exit Sub
           End If
       End If
   End If
   ```
4. [Added2] You can't assume that `Target` in `Worksheet_Change` will allways be a one-cell range. E.g. if I copy a value, select multiple cells and paste the value, I will change values of multiple cells at once and the `Target` of `Worksheet_Change` will be made of all the cells. Depending on what you want to do, you may want to evaluate just the first cell of the range or loop through all the cells:

   ```
   Dim cell as Excel.Range
   For Each cell In Target.Cells
       If Not Not Intersect(Range("A4", "H4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
           If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
               If Target.Value < 21 Then
                   Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
                   Exit Sub
               End If
           End If
       End If
       '...
   Next
   ```

   As a side note:

   - in general try to avoid `On Error Resume Next` and do a proper error handling
   - [Edited!] in your code, there is no need for the declaration of that many ranges. The could would be more readable if you write the ifs as `If Not Intersect(Range("A4", "H4"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my code a little bit, but have now some different issues, can you may take a look again? :)

Comment: @L.Writer you are welcome, but please put the old code in the question somewhere, otherwise it's a completely different question and the answer is outdated.

Comment: @L.Writer : Sorry, there was a mistake in the second side note: Intersect returns a Range, not a Boolean, therefore you need to check, if it is Nothing.
Btw. the strange behavior was caused by the `On Error Resume Next`. Every time the `Intersect` inside the `If` caused an error, it just jumped into the nested `If` and called the mailing function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now (code which I'm now using see above). Can you may tell me how I can get the cell value - 2x2 above the cell which triggers the event... For example if A4 is triggering the mail-event, I need the value of 'A2, A3' and 'B2, B3'. Or is it better to create another thread for that?

Comment: You're welcome. For the cells around use [Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel). There are good examples for that on the msdn page.

Comment: Can you may tell me how / where I need to implement the Range.Offset function?! Because inside the body (xMailBody) it's not possible. It willst just "True" be printed. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to send xMailBody the values as parameters - either as a range or a collection of values (I would suggest to send just the values as it is not a responsibility of mailing function to look up values in a sheet).

Comment: Btw. I have updated the answer with another issue of your code.